# Precedence operator 'OR' and '=' in PHP

Tags: php, assignment-operator, operator-precedence

```
$a = 1;
$a OR $a = 'somthing'
echo $a; //1
```

Why? If `=` have much precedence then 'OR' then why OR execute first?

Comment: Do you know formal grammars? If you knows formal grammar then read [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162919/unambiguous-grammar-for-exponentiation-operation/17170820#17170820) I explained how precedence useful to write grammar rules. And language writer decides precedence on the basis which statement should parse how decides precedence.

Comment: I added few more words in my answer please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if OR has higher precedence then

```
$a OR $a = 'somthing'
```

will be parsed as:

```
($a OR $a) = 'somthing'
```

that would be technically  wrong because you can't assign to an expression (while programmers would like to write expression like this is coding so it should be a valid expression).

because precedence of `or`  operator  was low hence the expression `$a OR $a = 'somthing'`  pareses as `$a OR ($a = 'somthing')` And according to short-circuit first operand that is `$a` was evaluated as `true` and second operand expression not evaluated and `a` remains `1`.

Remember precedence rules derives grammar rules and hence tells how expression will be parse. But precedence is a compile-time property that tells us how expressions are structured. Evaluation is a run-time behavior that tells us how expressions are computed (hence how expressions will be evaluates can't completely determine by precedence). And PHP docs seems to say same:

> [Operator Precedence](http://docs.php.net/language.operators.precedence#language.operators.precedence)
>   *Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions
>   are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation*. PHP does not
>   (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is
>   evaluated and code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should
>   be avoided, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or
>   depending on the surrounding code.

Comment: @user3271784 Your welcome. I just added a comment to Alireza Fallah's answer read that also. And if you knows formal grammars read linked answer.

Comment: @AlirezaFallah I added some more lines hope you find better.

Answer (score 2):

When you put OR between two statement, if the first one returns true, the second one never will be executed.

in this case, the first statement ( `$a` ) returns true ( because `$a = 1` ), so the

second one ( $`a = 'somthing';` )  wont be executed.

Comment: and also keep in mind that http://docs.php.net/language.operators.precedence says: `Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation.`

Comment: then, why 5+1*3 = 8 ? I think, * - have much precedence then +. Its right. In my case i think: $a = 'somthing' //do first (up precedence), then OR.

Comment: I disagree with your answer that don't explain why precedence of OR is higher then `=`

Comment: `$a OR $a = 'somthing'`, here , means `if(!$a) { $a = 'somthing' }`

Comment: @AlirezaFallah the information you added is correct and you understand correct, But just what I means it don't answers that "why precedence of OR is higher then =". this is because programmers usually like to write expressions like `$a OR $a = 'somthing'` And it should be pareses as  `$a OR ($a = 'somthing')` and to impose this constant language writers decided to keep precedence of `=` higher then OR.

Answer (score 1):

Because `1` is truthy.

What you're saying with `$a OR $a = 'somthing';`
is

> a is true **OR** set it to "somthing"

.
Well, a is true, so it won't be set, while the following code would do.

```
$a = false;
$a OR $a = 'somthing';
echo $a; //"something"
```