# how to find which operator has highest precedence in a grammar

Tags: expression, grammar, operator-precedence

I have an exam just the day after tomorrow. Please help me with this question and explain me the answer so that i could do all questions of this level in my exam.

Grammar is

```
E-> E/X | X
X-> T-X | X*T | T
T-> T+F | F
F-> (E) | id

id stands for identifier.
```

Q1 : Above grammar is used to generate all valid arithmetic expressions in a hypothetical language in which

```
a. / associates from the left
b. * associative from the left
c. + associative from the left
d. all of these
```

Q 2 : Above grammar is used to generate all valid arithmetic expressions in a hypothetical language in which

```
a.  + has the highest precedence
b.  * has the highest precedence
c.  - has the highest precedence
d.  / has the highest precedence
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a theoretical quastion, not an implementation problem. Might be better for Programmers.SE

Comment: A good question indeed. Read this answer [Unambiguous grammar for exponentiation operation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17170820/1673391) comment me back if you have doubts in my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unambiguous grammar for exponentiation operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162919/unambiguous-grammar-for-exponentiation-operation)

Answer (score 3):

let's put the level at each statements

```
E-> E/X | X....................1(root)
X-> T-X | X*T | T..............2
T-> T+F | F....................3
F-> (E) | id...................4
```

**Precedence**

op which is in the max level has the max precedence
so
id, (, ) has highest precedence folowed by + then -,* then /

so + has the highest precedence as per option

**Associativity**

Note A->Ax is left recursive and A-xA is right recursive grammer
Now

```
E-> E/X  is left recursive so / is left associated
X-> T-X is right recursive so - is right associated
X->  X*T is left recursive so / is left associated
T-> T+F | F is left recursive so / is left associated
```

so ans of Q1 is d :)