# Replace symbols in string

Tags: java

How to replace ^ into calling Math.pow() ?
For example:

```
str = "10 + 5.2^12"; // -> "10 + Math.pow(5.2, 12)"
str = "2^(12) + 6";  // -> "Math.pow(2, 12) + 6"
```

Comment: have you tried some code to achieve this? if so please post the same.

Comment: Are you look for an expression evaluator ?

Comment: I don't know how to describe it in regxp

Comment: Are the string always of the form `x + y^z` and `x^(y) + z` or can they contain an arithmetic expression of any form and length?

Comment: It seems like quite easy task. Can we see your attempts? You certainly read regex tutorial, right?

Comment: Yes, it may be any expression, but i need a func, to replase only ^ operator

Comment: Show plz an example how to find value in string by regxp

Comment: it´s a bit vague, are the values allways single number or can they be wrapped around a bracket for example?

Comment: @Letfar http://tinyurl.com/p74pyay

Comment: Show me how to get first index position of 5.2 in first case and the rest I'll do myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with regular expression in java.
Use the below code snippet to devide and replace the string.

```
private static String replaceMatchPow(String pValue) {
    String regEx = "(\\d*\\.*\\d*)\\^\\(*(\\d*\\.*\\d*)\\)*";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(pValue);
    if (m.find()) {
        String value = "Math.pow(" + m.group(1) + "," + m.group(2) + ")";
        pValue = pValue.replaceAll(regEx, value);
    }
    return pValue;
}
```

How the regex will work?
Here is the example for the input "2^(12) + 6"
1st group (\d*\.*\d*)
\d* -> match a digit [0-9], 
* -> zero to unlimited 
\^ -> divide the groups by ^ symbol
(* -> left bracket, * means occurrence zero to unlimited 
2nd group (\d*\.*\d*)
)* -> right bracket

Result: 1st group values is 2 and 2nd group values is 12

/(\d*.*\d*)\^(*(\d*.*\d*))*/

1st Capturing group (\d*.*\d*)

\d* match a digit [0-9]

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

.* matches the character . literally

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

\d* match a digit [0-9]

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

\^ matches the character ^ literally

(* matches the character ( literally

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

2nd Capturing group (\d*.*\d*)

\d* match a digit [0-9]

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

.* matches the character . literally

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

\d* match a digit [0-9]

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

)* matches the character ) literally

Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

Comment: could you explain the RegEx?

Comment: eg: 1st group (\\d*\\.*\\d*)       \d* ->  match a digit [0-9],   * -> zero to unlimited

Comment: \\^ -> divide the groups by ^ symbol

Comment: \\(* -> left bracket, * means occurrence zero to unlimited

Comment: 2nd group (\\d*\\.*\\d*)

Comment: \\)* -> right bracket

Comment: Thank you very much :) Is it possible you edit your post by adding the explanation? This will be helpful for the next people who are searching for the same help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\(?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)\\)?\\^\\(?(\\d+\\.?\\d*)\\)?", "Math.pow($1,$2)");
```

In this case, you are looking for 2 groups of digits `(\\d+\\.?\\d*)`, which could be a float value and can be inside of () `\\(?` and `\\)?`. Between this 2 groups, you need to have the ^ sign `\\^`. If it matches, then replaceAll method replaces all this pattern with `Math.pow($1,$2)`, where $1 and $2 will be replaced with first and second groups of digits.

But one thing, it could lead to wrong results if you have a complicated expression, with 2 multiplications in a row, like a `10.22^31.22^5`. In this case, this regular expression should be much more complicated. And may be you should use some other algorithm to parse such expressions.

Comment: could you explain the RegEx?

Comment: was already editing an answer. added the short explanation

Comment: Who downvoted, and why ?

Comment: I did not if you're asking me... I did upvote btw

Answer (score 0):

For your special problem you should lookup how the caret character ^ is escaped in [Java regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), it should be `\^`.

Note that:

> Backslashes within string literals in Java source code are interpreted
>   as required by The Java™ Language Specification as either Unicode
>   escapes (section 3.3) or other character escapes (section 3.10.6) It
>   is therefore necessary to double backslashes in string literals that
>   represent regular expressions to protect them from interpretation by
>   the Java bytecode compiler.

So you end up with `"\\^"` as a Java `String`.

However in general you will write a parser and interpreter for arithmetical expressions.

This subject is known as compiler construction and relies on knowledge of finite automata and formal languages.

A nice example can be found in chapter 10.2 "A Desk Calculator" of "The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition" by Bjarne Stroustrup. (Yes, I know you want to code in Java, please continue to read).
It features this formal grammar:

```
program:
  end //end is end-of-input
  expr_list end

expr_list:
  expression print  //pr intis newline or semicolon
  expression print expr_list

expression:
  expression + term
  expression − term
  term

term:
  term / primary
  term ∗ primary
  primary

primary:
  number //number is a ﬂoating-point literal
  name //name is an identiﬁer
  name = expression
  −primary
  ( expression )
```

Stroustrup shows you how to code this in a similar structure:

```
double expr(bool get) //add and subtract
{
  double left = term(get);
  for(;;) { //‘‘forever’’
    switch(ts.current().kind) {
    case Kind::plus:
      left += term(true);
      break;
    case Kind::minus:
      left −= term(true);
      break;
    default:
      return left;
    }
  }
}
```

this code embodies this part of the grammar:

```
expression:
  expression + term
  expression − term
  term
```

This technique is called *recursive descent*, because recursion in the grammar will be implemented as a recursive function call in the corresponding code. The featured relevant C++ code should be understandable to a Java developer as well.

Once you got a bit familiar with grammars and how to implement them,
see e.g. [Unambiguous grammar for exponentiation operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162919/unambiguous-grammar-for-exponentiation-operation)
how to deal with exponentiation in such a way, that the usual operator precedence rules are fulfilled.